# Change front fragment when clicking an item on a SlidingMenu 

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to make a sliding menu just like Youtube or Google+ app.

I'm following [this](https://github.com/iPaulPro/SlidingMenu) project code, and what I'm trying to do is when I click on an item on the left bar, the Activity slides back to left with the new content.

> just like when you are on Google+ **home** screen, and you click the **profile** item on the left menu and it slides back to left with the **profile** screen loaded.

So here is my code.

I have this main activity called **ExampleActivity.java**:

```
    public class ExampleActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity
{
    //public PagerAdapter adapter;
    public FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // set the Behind View
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, new SampleListFragment()).commit();

        // customize the SlidingMenu
        this.setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true); 
        getSlidingMenu().setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        getSlidingMenu().setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.actionbar_home_width); 
        getSlidingMenu().setBehindScrollScale(0.25f);
        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);

        // customize the ActionBar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                toggle();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And I have the **SampleListFragment.java** which handles the clicks on the left menu.

```
    public class SampleListFragment extends ListFragment
{
    private ExampleActivity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mActivity = (ExampleActivity)getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        Fragment frag = null;

        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                frag = new FirstFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                frag = new SecondFragment();
                break;
        }

        if (frag != null)
            replaceFragment(frag);
    }

    protected void replaceFragment(Fragment frag)
    {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main, frag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        mActivity.showAbove();
    }

    /**
     * A callback function, executed when this fragment is attached to an
     * activity
     */
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        return v;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            adapter.add(new SampleItem(new Fragment(), "Sample List",
                    android.R.drawable.btn_star));
        }
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class SampleItem
    {
        public Fragment frag;
        public String tag;
        public int iconRes;

        public SampleItem(Fragment fram, String tag, int iconRes)
        {
            this.frag = frag;
            this.tag = tag;
            this.iconRes = iconRes;
        }
    }

    public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem>
    {
        public SampleAdapter(Context context)
        {
            super(context, 0);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.row, null);
            }

            ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.row_title);

            convertView.setTag(title.getText().toString());

            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

So what happens, when I click the first item on the left menu, the FirstFragment() is called, the toast is shown but the layout is not added to the activity.

**Here is the code for FirstFragment class:**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment
{
    private ExampleActivity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstfragment, container, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textView.setText("Lorem ipsum");

        return fragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    { 
        super.onResume();
        mActivity = (ExampleActivity)getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "First Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }
}
```

Here is the layout for the **ExampleActivity.java** which is **main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:text="Random Button!"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Question**

How do I add the first fragment layout to the activity. It keeps showing the initial layout, but the layout of the fragment is not loaded into the activity.

Thank you.

Comment: You should start off small (using normal layouts without fragments) and move upwards so you can ask a question which tightly focuses on where your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this tutorial on android documentation and it worked.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html